# Django apache server not stable

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have setup django with apache web server. It work but I noticed something strange.

Sometimes, the page that I load working normally. Then, if I press refresh it becomes error, page not found. If I keep refreshing, sometimes it returns to normal page sometimes it becomes error. After I restart apache, it always works fine.

I noticed this strange behavior appear if I tried to access some page that doesn't exist and give page not found error. Then, if I return back to the correct page, the strange behavior appears. It is as if the server or django has some cache to the error and then randomly display it.

How should I handle this?

EDIT:

Okay, it seems I know what happened. First of all, if I use apache+mod_wsgi, whenever I add some url, I need to restart the web server OR touch the wsgi app. Second, the trailing / in the end of the url really matter. I tried to access `localhost/myproject/myapp` is different from `localhost/myproject/myapp/`. That is why I got weird result.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: How is your server deployed? What WSGI app are you using? How are you forwarding requests from apache to django?

Comment: I use really basic setting. I use apache + wsgi module and setup some virtual host. If I access django admin, it gives correct page. As for the code, I follow : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

I just try to add a new view like in the tutorial. I will add more detail if I know more about this.

Comment: I believe this is cache problem because at some points, I tried to add new app in my project (myfirstdjango). The app name is catalog. Then add index view in the calatog app and add the url accordingly. 
After I got this weird behaviour,I decided to delete the project folder, myfirstdjango. Then I tried to redo it from the beginning but with the same project name, myfirstdjango. I create app in this new project, I add new app with the name polls. When I got the page not found error, the error still display catalog app url that I created before although I have deleted the old project folder.